# Regex Forward and Backward looking patterns

Tags: regex

Hi I am very new to regex but would like to construct something that will match on the word "Public" | "Private" | "Protected" and the following word (to grab the following word), unless the following word is not: void, string, int, bool. The bolded word matches can be any word except for the ones listed above.

Sample Matches:

- Public xyz Functionname (match)
- Public abc Functionname (match)
- Private rbc Functionname (match)
- Protected klm Functionname (match)

Sample Non-matches:

- Public void Functionname (non-match)
- Public string Functionname (non-match)
- Public int Functionname (non-match)

I got as far as this but it's not really working properly:

```
^((Public)|(Private)|(Protected)).*$(?<!Void|string|int)
```

Comment: in what flavor of regex?  perl regex and javascript regex are worlds apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
\b(?:public|private|protected)\s+(?!void|string|int|bool)(\w+)\s+
```

*After a word break, match (but don't capture) `public` or `private` or `protected`, then one or more whitespace characters, then  one or more "word" characters as long as the word is not `void` or `string` or `int` or `bool`.*

Seems to work in my tests.

**Edit**
To exclude matches that end with `get;` or `set;`, it's a bit more complicated but this appears to work:

```
\b(?:public|private|protected)\s+(?!void|string|int|bool)(\w+)\s+((?!(get;|set;)$).)*$
```

which I just like the first one with the addition of *followed by any number of any character that is not followed by a `get;` or a `set;` which ends the line*

That will match `Public xyz Functionname get; with other stuff` but not `Public xyz Functionname get;`. If the former should be excluded as well, just drop the second to last `$`, and then a match will be discarded if there's a `get;` or `set;` anywhere after the first section.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will fail for the following code: `foopublic abc` .  See my answer below for a revised regex.

Comment: thanks factor Mystic. how would i also modify this to exclude any lines that end with:    get; set;    ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
^(Public|Private|Protected) (?!void|string|int).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't seem to jibe with your examples, but this matches the examples:

```
^(Public|Private|Protected)\s+(?!void|string|int|bool)(\w+)\s+(\w+)
```

Basically, you want to use **lookahead**, not *lookbehind*.  Lookbehinds aren't nearly as useful as most people expect them to be.  In fact, most regex flavors would treat *your* lookbehind as a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers do not properly utilize word boundaries and will fail for the following:

```
foopublic abc (FactorMystic's regex)
Public voidxyz Functionname (Alan Moore's regex)
```

In most programming languages, a variable identifier which contains a reserved word with additional characters is still valid.  For example, if `function` is a reserved word, a variable identifier of `myfunction` is still valid.

Here is a revised regex:

```
\b(Public|Private|Protected)\s+(?!(?:void|string|int|bool)\b)(\w+)
```

If you are using this for syntax highlighting, I recommend writing an actual parser.  Regex-based syntax highlighters can be inaccurate, and most flavors of regex aren't particularly great when dealing with nested constructs.